# V hosts issue - Couldn't load webpage - Keep loading but no result

Tags: apache, mamp, virtualhost, vhosts

I'm trying to set up a local website, using virtual host.
I'm working on Mac big sur 11.6 - Mamp 6.3 /apache.
Bellow is the configuration of the file: /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "/Users/THE_USER/sites/symfart/public/"
ServerName  symfart.local
</VirtualHost>
```

And here is the config of the file /etc/hosts:
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
127.0.0.1       symfart.local

I already updated the file
/Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/httpd.conf and uncommented the 2 lines :
LoadModule vhost_alias_module modules/mod_vhost_alias.so
And
Include /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

NO ERROR > PAGE KEEPS LOADING AND NO RESULT (like an infinite loop)
Thanks your help

Answer (score 0):

After research I figured out that I was missing a .htaccess file in the Public folder.
This is Its content :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

# Determine the RewriteBase automatically and set it as environment variable.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

# If the requested filename exists, simply serve it.
# We only want to let Apache serve files and not directories.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule .? - [L]

# Rewrite all other queries to the front controller.
RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```